# Instagram scraping to get usernames who liked a particular media

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

I need to integrate Instagram scraping functionality in my current ROR app to get those usernames who liked a given media.

I am able to scrape the data from an instagram media link successfully. The Url i used for this is in format `"https://www.instagram.com/p/:media_id"`. But the problem is that i am only getting first 10 users who liked the media.

Also, I read somewhere that we have to pass `end_cursor` param to get next set of records. So, I tried changing url to `"https://www.instagram.com/p/:media_id?max_id=end_cursor_value_from_response_of_first_url"`. But, still getting same records as in previous request.

Is there a way to get the list of all usernames (and not just the first 10) who liked the media?

**Note:** I can also use **Graphql** query. So, If someone has solution that uses Graphql query, then it would be perfect for me.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**Updates**

I tried using Graphql query. Please find the query below:

```
media_id = 'MY_MEDIA_ID'
cursor_end = "CURSOR END TOKEN"
query_id = 'MY_QUERY_HASH_WHICH_I_COPIED_FROM_BROWSER'
escaped_variables_1 = CGI.escape({'shortcode': media_id, 'first': 50, 'after': cursor_end}.to_json)
url = "https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=#{query_id}&variables=#{escaped_variables_1}"

uri = URI.parse(url)

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request['Cookie'] = "ig_pr=1"
http.request(request)
```

But that too didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using https://github.com/caseyscarborough/instagram?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Instagram API has been changed vastly in last 2 months.
They have removed many endpoints

Comment: Hmm. I don't see the list of users who likes a media in their response, only the count of likes.